# Python Counter add and subtract

Tags: python, html, forms

I got the counter working  I am pretty sure I got the post get working. Could someone look at my code and tell me where it went wrong. The code keeps count of Sessions. I want the ninja button to +2 and the hacker to reset to 1.  Got all of it but the last two parts. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'F12Zr47j\3yX R~X@H!jmM]Lwf/,?KT'


def sumSessionCounter():
  try:
    session['counter'] += 1
  except KeyError:
    session['counter'] = 1


@app.route('/')
def index():
    sumSessionCounter()
    return render_template('index.html')


def contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['ninja'] == session['counter'] + 2:
            pass # do something
        elif request.form['hacker'] == session['counter'] - session['counter'] + 1 :
            pass # do something else

            pass # unknown
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)





app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylenew.css"></style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script> 
  <script>


  </script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>{{session['counter']}}</h1>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="ninja"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="hacker"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you **decrement** instead of assign `1`: `session['counter'] -= 1` instead of `session['counter'] = 1`?

Comment: That just throws an error due to the = sign being invalid syntax.

Comment: your code doesnt make sense, `if request.form['ninja']` then do `session['counter'] += 2` is what your expected code looks like as per what you explained!!!

Comment: Yea so if the submit button is clicked for either ninja or hacked it should to that function. However its not. At least from what I see it should.

Comment: @DavidHollenbeck what you expect to achieve from this line of code `if request.form['ninja'] == session['counter'] + 2` ?

Comment: The sessions counter to go up by two

Comment: not sure if it is part of flask (*which i don't know*) but it is DEFINITELY not how python works buddy!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137555/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-david-hollenbeck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding some Ajax calls would be better here. In your `app.py`, add a route:

```
@app.route('/sessionCounter')
def sessionCounter():
    message = request.args.get('message', 'reset')
    if message == 'add':
        try:
            session['counter'] += 2
        except KeyError:
            session['counter'] = 1
    elif message == 'reset':
        session['counter'] = 1
    return jsonify(result=session['counter'])  # need to import jsonify from flask
```

I'm also assuming that you're using your `contact.html` as the template for this particular HTML view. Therefore, your `app.py` needs a route that renders the template:

```
@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html', session=session)
```

Now in your contact HTML, you need to add the JS code to handle the button clicks and modify the buttons themselves:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylenew.css"></style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('button#add').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/sessionCounter', {
          message: 'add'
        }, function(data) {
          $("#result").text(data.result);
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
    $(function() {
      $('button#reset').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/sessionCounter', {
          message: 'reset'
        }, function(data) {
          $("#result").text(data.result);
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id='result'>{{session['counter']}}</h1>

<p><button id="add">Ninja</button></p>
<p><button id="reset">Hacker</button></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Now start up your app, and goto `http://localhost:5000/contact`, and click around :)

Comment: Ty for looking at it. What you wrote makes since however no i dont know why i had contact in there just goes to index I just need to figure out why sessions counter not showing on the page i cant test it atm to see if this works

Comment: Ok, if you're looking to use the `index` route, then I would just change `@app.route('/contact')` to `@app.route('/index')` and `return render_template('contact.html', session=session)` to `return render_template('index.html', session=session)`. Probably change the `def contact()` function for your route to `def index()` as well :)